# Converting structured data into a table in RDBMS

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, rdbms

I have the following structure which I want to convert into a table( RDBMS ).

```
1)
Structure(
      // 1st entry
      "HK"
      Structure(
      "Aggressive Price", 100
      "Passive Price",    90,
      "Quantity", 1000
      "Tick Ladder", [ [ 0.1, 1 ],
                       [ 0.2, 2 ],
                       [ 0.3, 3 ] 
                     ]
      ),                  
     //2nd entry
     "JP",
      Structure(
      "Aggressive Price", 100
      "Passive Price",    90,
      "Quantity", 1000
      "Tick Ladder", [ [ 0.1, 1 ],
                       [ 0.2, 2 ],
                       [ 0.3, 3 ] 
                     ],
      Aggressive limits, Structure( "ABC", 10, "SCD", 20 )
      )         
)         

2)
Structure(
      // 1st entry
      "Algo1"
      Structure(
      "Aggressive Price", 100
      "Passive Price",    90,
      "Quantity", 1000
      "Tick Ladder", [ [ 0.1, 1 ],
                       [ 0.2, 2 ],
                       [ 0.3, 3 ] 
                     ]
      ),                  
     //Second entry
     "JP",
      Structure(
      "Aggressive Price", 100
      "Passive Price",    90,
      "Quantity", 1000
      "Tick Ladder", [ [ 0.1, 1 ],
                       [ 0.2, 2 ],
                       [ 0.3, 3 ] 
                     ],
      Aggressive limits, Structure( "ABC", 10, "SCD", 20 )
      )         
)         

Structure(
      // 1st entry
      "Algo2"
      Structure(
      "Aggressive Price", 100
      "Passive Price",    90,
      "Quantity", 1000
      "Tick Ladder", [ [ 0.1, 1 ],
                       [ 0.2, 2 ],
                       [ 0.3, 3 ] 
                     ]
      ),                  
     //Second entry
     "JP",
      Structure(
      "Aggressive Price", 100
      "Passive Price",    90,
      "Quantity", 1000
      "Tick Ladder", [ [ 0.1, 1 ],
                       [ 0.2, 2 ],
                       [ 0.3, 3 ] 
                     ],
      Aggressive limits, Structure( "ABC", 10, "SCD", 20 )
      )         
)
```

1) -- Contains parameters for the country "HK" & "JP".

2) -- Contains the same parameters for "Algo1" and "Algo2". The values of the parameters can vary. What's the best way to represent this as a relation schema.

Solution I'm thinking of

1) A table "Parameters" with Aggressive Price, Passive Price, Quantity, Tick Ladder

2) A table "Country" which reference table parameter

3) A table "Algo" which references table parameter

4) A table "Ladder" to store ladder values which would be referenced by the "Parameter" array.

How to generate unique keys for "Country" table referencing "Parameters" and so on ?

Any other better methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this way off the mark?

```
create table countries (country_code char(2) primary key,
                        country longtext);

create table algos (pk char(40) primary key,
                    country_code_fk char(2),
                    aggressive_price decimal(8,2),
                    passive_price decimal(8,2),
                    quantity int,
                    tick_ladder enum);

create table aggressive_limits (algo_fk char(40),
                                field_0 char(3),
                                field_1 int,
                                field_2 char(3),
                                field_3 int);
```